# ¿Consultar hijos de una tabla padre a través de ID?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

estoy trabajando en una base de datos en la cual tengo una tabla de procesos y otra de dependencias de los mismos procesos ya que hay procesos que dependen de otros.

La cuestión aquí es que las tablas están de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla Procesos le hereda el id_proceso a la tabla dependencia y en la columna id_proceso2 se inserta el id_proceso de otros procesos que dependen del proceso que se registre en id_proceso (espero haberlo explicado bien).
Lo que necesito es recuperar el proceso y sus dependientes, logre hacerlo concatenando los id que pertenecen a cierto proceso, pero me resultan asi:

[image: PROCESO | DEPENDIENTES 5621 | 125, 268, 96]

Lo que requiero es traer el nombre en lugar de los id de los dependientes, ya intente de distintas formas y no doy, espero puedan ayudarme.
Actualmente lo que mas me ayudo fue esto:

```
select d.id_proceso as proceso, listagg(id_proceso2,', ') as dependientes
from dependendia d
where d.id_proceso
in (select id_proceso from procesos)
group by d.id_proceso
order by d.id_proceso;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select d.id_proceso as proceso, listagg(p.Nom_Proceso, ', ') as dependientes
from dependencia d inner join procesos p 
on d.id_proceso2 = p.id_proceso 
where d.id_proceso
in (select id_proceso from procesos)
group by d.id_proceso
order by d.id_proceso;
```

A tu consulta original le añades la **cláusula inner join** juntando de esta forma las **tablas Procesos** y **Dependencia** por los campos en común **id_proceso2** de la **tabla Dependencia** y el campo **idproceso**  de la **tabla Procesos**, una vez que haces esta relación puedes usar en la **función de agregación listagg** el **campo Nom_Proceso**.